# How do you read the system time and date in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime

I need to read the system clock (time and date) and display it in a human-readable format in Perl.

Currently, I'm using the following method (which I found [here](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/perllocaltime_2.htm)):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
@months = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);
@weekDays = qw(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun);
($second, $minute, $hour, $dayOfMonth, $month, $yearOffset, $dayOfWeek, $dayOfYear, $daylightSavings) = localtime();
$year = 1900 + $yearOffset;
$theTime = "$hour:$minute:$second, $weekDays[$dayOfWeek] $months[$month] $dayOfMonth, $year";
print $theTime;
```

> When you run the program, you should see a much more readable date and time like this:

```
9:14:42, Wed Dec 28, 2005
```

This seems like it's more for illustration than for actual production code.  Is there a more canonical way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) function:

> In scalar context, localtime() returns
>   the ctime(3) value:
>
> ```
> $now_string = localtime;  # e.g., "Thu Oct 13 04:54:34 1994"
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I was making it a lot harder than it needed to be. :)

Comment: Note that 'localtime' is the (a?) US format of the local time; if you really want to provide the output, you have to work a bit harder.

Answer (score 14):

You can use localtime to get the time and the POSIX module's [`strftime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime) to format it.

While it'd be nice to use Date::Format's and its strftime because it uses less overhead, the POSIX module is distributed with Perl, and is thus pretty much guaranteed to be on a given system.

```
use POSIX;
print POSIX::strftime( "%A, %B %d, %Y", localtime());
# Should print something like Wednesday, January 28, 2009
# ...if you're using an English locale, that is.
# Note that this and Date::Format's strftime are pretty much identical
```

Comment: In modern Perl >=5.10 I would also recommend Time::Piece (http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

Answer (score 9):

As everyone else said "localtime" is how you tame date, in an easy and straight forward way.

But just to give you one more option. The [DateTime module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime). This module has become a bit of a favorite of mine.

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now;

my $dow = $dt->day_name;
my $dom = $dt->mday;
my $month = $dt->month_abbr;
my $chr_era = $dt->year_with_christian_era;

print "Today is $dow, $month $dom $chr_era\n";
```

This would print "Today is Wednesday, Jan 28 2009AD". Just to show off a few of the many things it can do.

```
use DateTime;
print DateTime->now->ymd;
```

It prints out "2009-01-28"

Comment: And, for ultimate flexibility, a DateTime object has a `strftime` method.

Answer (score 8):

Like someone else mentioned, you can use localtime, but I would parse it with [Date::Format](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TimeDate/lib/Date/Format.pm). It'll give you the timestamp formatted in pretty much any way you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll definitely need that to put the date/time in the standard U.S. format.

Comment: Permalink to [Date::Format](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TimeDate/lib/Date/Format.pm)

Comment: Date::Format seems pretty pointless. As people have mentioned, POSIX::strftime does all of that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one-liner print statement to print localtime in clear, readable format is:

```
print scalar localtime (); #Output: Fri Nov 22 14:25:58 2019
```