# Why does DateTime add a T separator to the timestamp?

Tags: perl, datetime

My code:

```
print DateTime->now;
```

Response:

> 2012-08-17T20:16:37

Why is there a T? Is there an option I have forgotten?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `T` is just a standard (ISO 8601) way to delimit the *time*. To use a different format, consider using [`strftime`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.76/lib/DateTime.pm#strftime_Patterns) or [`format_cldr`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.76/lib/DateTime.pm#CLDR_Patterns).

For example, to have a space instead, use `DateTime->now->format_cldr("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`.

Answer (score 4):

Stringifying a `DateTime` object uses the ISO 8601 format unless you have specified a formatter in the constructor. See [Formatters and Stringification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime#Formatters_And_Stringification) in the docs.
The `iso8601` method is:

```
sub iso8601 { join 'T', $_[0]->ymd('-'), $_[0]->hms(':') }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's default output format [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) produces, ISO-8601. If you want something else, you need to use the `strftime` or `format_cldr` methods or one of the `DateTime::Format::*` modules to output a different format, e.g.:

```
print DateTime->now->format_cldr("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the iso standard for date and time, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

see e.g. [How do you read the system time and date in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487791/how-do-you-read-the-system-time-and-date-in-perl) for a discussion on reading date/time in a formatable way.