# what format is this datetime string: 2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

I need to generate a `MessageTime` for a xml based api. In the example request file, they are using the following:

```
<MessageTime>2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00</MessageTime>
```

What is the format of this datetime string? I want to generate it using `date()` method or `DateTime` class.

This is what I tried so far: *I am in the UK, so i am using the offset `00:00`*

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s').'-00:00')
// Output: 2014-05-26T20:11:45-00:00
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5):

```
date('c');
```

Or using a constant:

```
date(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

You can also utilize `O` for the "difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours":

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Does this use the php's datetime zone to get the offset? I'll accept this answer when I am able to.

Comment: And yes @LatheesanKanes `date()` will use PHP's default timezone to get offsets.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I don't know why this question is marked as duplicate and pointing to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012689/why-does-datetime-add-a-t-separator-to-the-timestamp (this quuestion maybe similar, but it was about `perl` NOT `php`.)

Comment: It is marked as a dupe because, despite the different language, the answer is the same. DateTime formats are, for the most part, language agnostic.

Comment: @vascowhite I still wouldn't call it a duplicate.  The other question was specifically asking about the `T` added, and received explanations on ISO 8601. OP here was trying to recreate ISO 8601 in PHP (specifically having issues with getting the offset).