# Django template convert datetime-local format

Tags: html, datetime, django-templates, datetime-format, django-3.0

I'm having a problem on how will I convert the `datetime` format from my `db` to `html` `datetime-local`. Here's the data format in my database:

```
2020-07-18T17:25:00Z
```

When I'm trying to pass this data to html input with a type of `datetime-local` it is giving me a warning like this:
[image]

Here's my html code with the formatted value:

```
<input type="datetime-local" required="" value="{{order.pick_up_datetime|date:'Y-m-dTh:i a'}}">
```

Answer (score 6):

After a day of debugging, I got the answer in my question here. I just did something like this:

```
<input type="datetime-local" required="" value="{{order.pick_up_datetime|date:'Y-m-d'}}T{{order.pick_up_datetime|time:'H:i:s'}}">
```

Just separate the value of `date` and `time` in the value and added a `T` (The `T` is just a `standard (ISO 8601)` way to delimit the *time*).

The answer here help me to realize and solve my problem: [Why does DateTime add a T separator to the timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012689/why-does-datetime-add-a-t-separator-to-the-timestamp)