# How to get the current time in date time in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime, timestamp

I'm writing a Perl script that takes the current time in the datetime format. How can I get the current time stored to a variable in the datetime format in Perl?

Comment: `perldoc -f localtime`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487791/how-do-you-read-the-system-time-and-date-in-perl

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;    
my $dt   = DateTime->now;   # Stores current date and time as datetime object
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use "localtime()" to return EPOCH time.

You can convert it to string time. If that's what you want.

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **strftime** in the standard POSIX module:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%F %T", localtime $^T'
```

The arguments to **strftime** in Perl's binding were designed to align with the return values from **localtime** and **gmtime**.